# How can I quickly make a long string of 3-pin components?

Tags: sensor, connector, 1-wire

I prepared a 7 m long strip with 7 DS18B20 and, lacking a better idea, I soldered the DS18B20 pins directly to wires, where all but the last sensor have a 3-point star connection: DS18B20 leg, wire to microcontroller, wire to next DS18B20.

To give some strength and to isolate the pins I used hot glue (it's compatible with the final temperature range).

See in the photo.

However, the procedure is very time consuming and taking away the glue, in case of corrections, may damage the pins.

Keeping in mind that (as I found out later) short stubs are allowed by 1-Wire communication, how could I speed up the process? which other connection techniques can I use to do Y connections ending with a similar component? soldering is of course allowed, but avoiding having to keep two wires carefully positioned would be already an improvement.

I also see components like the ones in the second photo but they are only for two wires so I would need two per sensor. Also, I'm not sure they work well for stranded wires.

My work: 
[image: My work]

T splitters:
[image: T splitters]

Comment: You could make PCBs with connectors on them. If you want to use insulation displacement, there are RJ type modular connectors that are cheap and fairly reliable.

Comment: True, I didn't think about PCBs. They are quite cheap nowadays.